# Can this be an alignement memory issue?

Tags: c, memory, alignment

I have one struct that is mapped to a byte array. But I found that it seems not all fields are correctly mapped. I'm wondering if this is an alignment problem or a bug.

```
struct _sg64_struct
{
  SG64_PCSC_TLV_HEADER header; /* This is 2 bytes */
  gint8 id_perso;
  gint8 status;
  gint8 fare_type;  
  gint16 fare_zone;     
  gint8 support_type;   
  gchar loginPerso[15];
};
```

I have this structure to be mapped to this bytes:

41150002000000000E2020202020202020202020202020

But I found that support_type gets 0x0E value instead of 00 as is supposed to be. If we map it

```
    struct _sg64_struct
{
  SG64_PCSC_TLV_HEADER header; 4115
  gint8 id_perso; 00
  gint8 status;   02
  gint8 fare_type;  00
  gint16 fare_zone;     0000
  gint8 support_type;   00
  gchar loginPerso[15]; E2020202020202020202020202020
};
```

But I get as I said support_type with 0E. Strange thing is that if I map fare_zone as two bytes it works.

```
struct _sg64_struct
{
  SG64_PCSC_TLV_HEADER header; /* This is 2 bytes */
  gint8 id_perso;
  gint8 status;
  gint8 fare_type;  
  gint8 fare_zone[2];   
  gint8 support_type;   
  gchar loginPerso[15];
};
```

This structure works. But the question is why? Can we trust the compiler types?

Comment: Padding issue? See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Yes, this looks like a typical alignment behavior. Unless you really have to for very good reasons you shouldn't map a struct to a byte sequence, just decode the byte stream into the struct manually. It's the most portable and safe way to do things.

Comment: Many compilers support `#pragma`s to modify struct packing. If you are OK with making the code less portable you should look up `#pragma pack`.

Comment: Notice that `#pragma pack` is a machine gun readily pointed at your foot.

Comment: You expect the fare_zone member to have an offset of 5.  Default alignment rules for a 16-bit integer gives it an offset of 6 by inserting one byte of padding.  That keeps processors happy that don't have a multiplexer that can shuffle the mis-aligned bytes.  Compilers have a non-standard extension to disable this padding, like `__attribute__ ((packed))`.  You need to fret about endian-ness as well, no simple fix for that.

Comment: In fact we are dealing with few different architectures. One is x86_64, then ARM32 and smartcards, and desfire... So yes, I think this kind of alignement errors are a gun pointing your foot. But that's the way was done and I have to deal with it best way. So what's better? Pragma, manually map or what?

Comment: @Art But that's the way of serializing to disk in C. So if I cannot save and load structures directly why do I want a structure? I would map the bytes to stand alone variables, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of each member of the structure usually has a default alignment, meaning that it will, unless otherwise requested by the programmer, be aligned on a pre-determined boundary.

> gint8
>
> **typedef signed char gint8;**
>
> *A signed integer guaranteed to be 8 bits on all platforms.*

and

> gint16
>
> **typedef signed short gint16;**
>
> *An unsigned integer guaranteed to be 8 bits on all platforms.*

When you have `gint16` type of `fare_zone` in your structure, the compiler is padding `struct _sg64_struct` with 1 byte to **align `fare_zone`**.

So, this is happening with your structure when the `fare_zone` is of type `gint16`:

```
struct _sg64_struct
{
  SG64_PCSC_TLV_HEADER header;  // 2 bytes  4115
  gint8 id_perso;               // 1 byte   00 
  gint8 status;                 // 1 byte   02
  gint8 fare_type;              // 1 byte   00
  gchar pad[1];         <------ // 1 byte   00 (compiler is padding 1 byte to align fare_zone, as short type are 2-byte aligned)
  gint16 fare_zone;             // 2 byte   0000   
  gint8 support_type;           // 1 byte   0E
  gchar loginPerso[15];         // 15 byte  2020202020202020202020202020
};
```

And that's why `support_type` gets 0x0E value instead of 00.

When you have `gint8` type of `fare_zone` in your structure, the compiler is padding size of `struct _sg64_struct` with 1 byte to **alignment boundary** and doing trailing padding.

```
struct _sg64_struct
{
  SG64_PCSC_TLV_HEADER header; // 2bytes     4115
  gint8 id_perso;              // 1 byte     00
  gint8 status;                // 1 byte     02
  gint8 fare_type;             // 1 byte     00
  gint8 fare_zone[2];          // 2 byte     0000 (no alignment required as the char types are 1 byte aligned)
  gint8 support_type;          // 1 byte     00
  gchar loginPerso[15];        // 15 byte    0E2020202020202020202020202020
  gchar pad[1];        <------ // Compiler is padding 1 byte to alignment boundary of structure
};
```

And that's why this structure works.

I would suggest not to map the structure with the sequence of bytes as the alignment of structure members might be vary based on the compiler and underlying platform.

---

**Additional note:**

Every modern compiler will automatically use data structure padding depending on architecture. Some compilers even support the warning flag `-Wpadded` which generates helpful warnings about structure padding. These warnings help the programmer take manual care in case a more efficient data structure layout is desired.

> **-Wpadded**
>
> Warn if padding is included in a structure, **either to align an element
>   of the structure or to align the whole structure**. Sometimes when this
>   happens it is possible to rearrange the fields of the structure to
>   reduce the padding and so make the structure smaller.

So, if your compiler supports warning flag `-Wpadded`, try compiling your code with it. That will help you in understanding the padding included in a structure by the compiler.

Comment: Great explanation. Since I have to deal with it and using gcc on all architectures I will try to enable the -Wpadded and carefully pad on each architecture. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because there is padding inside the structure. This is a very bad practice. The assumption that the offset of a struct member is simply the sum of all preceeding members' sizes is wrong.